# What is the intuition behind taking the sum of square roots, squared

Tags: mathematical-statistics, scales, psychometrics

In a recent publication, the authors report the following transformation when aggregating across three different scales:

> Cognitive style level was used as a control variable and captured as
>   `(sqrt(OV) + sqrt(SV) + sqrt(V))^2` which is similar to, but a more
>   robust measure than, the sum of the means of the three cognitive
>   styles, particularly when team size varies. It captures both the level
>   and the range of the member cognitive styles in the team (Matousek
>   2002, Rudin 1987).

The referenced publications are both lengthy real analysis textbooks, which don't provide a clear intuition for why this is valuable.  What is the intuition behind this?  Are there more robust transformations?

Comment: $\left( |x_1|^p + |x_2|^p + \ldots + |x_n|^p \right)^{1/p}$ for $p \geq 1$ is known as the [p-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm). For $p=2$, it is the classic [Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance). Your case though is $p = \frac{1}{2}$ which makes the measure concave (rather than [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function)) and hence isn't a norm (because it doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality: the norm of a sum is less than the sum of the norms). This isn't my field and don't know why a concave measure would be desired.

Comment: The threads at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3682 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244202 will illuminate this.  @Matthew being a norm is not important.  This is a multiple of a "root mean;" it lies on a continuum between the arithmetic mean ($p=1$), geometric mean ($p=0$), and harmonic mean ($p=-1$).  You can see how closely it is tied to the Box-Cox family of transformations.